# How to scale a torus only on y or x axis that will have the same radius on every major segment?

Tags: modeling

I want a mesh that's a stretched torus (like to this shape)[image: the head]
but when I scale it only on y or x axis, the segments that are closer to the axis they were scaled on are thicker, I can't select half of it and extrude it, because that would be more like a chain link[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an ellipse curve, if you decide to do it by scaling on one axis, remember that scaling in *Object Mode* scales the object after modifiers, so after beveling. In order to scale in *Edit Mode* to scale before modifiers, you need to set handle types to *aligned:*

[image]

Then in *Object Data Properties > Geometry > Bevel:*

[image]

[image]

Then menu *Object > Convert > Mesh:*

[image]

Comment: May pay to expand on adding ellipse curve for new users.

Comment: How can I make the ellipse? When I scale it it's the same problem like with the mesh, and when I apply the scale it gets more angular

Comment: @batFINGER scaling in Edit Mode .. works with NURBS, but not Bezier..  (doesn't scale the handles appropriately). Anonymous: For a Bezier ellipse, either convert, or use the shipped add-on 'Add Curve: Extra Objects'

Comment: Edited this in, though I don't know how good my method is - it's an equivalent to scaling in *Object Mode*...